dns resolve throw syscall linux
please help. this code sometime works but sometimes not working
it retreive responce for dns
sometimes it long wait from function recv (and no answer) but sometime all working good
i compiled it by 2 commands jwasm and gcc linux
JWasm212\JWasm.exe -elf64 -Fo=test.o test.asm

gcc -o test.out test.o -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs --disable-shared -no-pie

sometimes it long wait from function recv (and no answer) but sometime all working good
code:
public _start

 socket             equ     41
 connect            equ     42
 sendto             equ     44
 recv               equ     45
 exit_group         equ     231

 sockaddr_in struct
 
         sin_family    dw        ?
         sin_port      dw        ?
         sin_addr      dd        ?
         sin_zero      db 8 dup (?)
     
     sockaddr_in ends
 
 .data
 
queryheader db  00h, 03h ; AA AA - ID
            db  01h, 00h ; 01 00 - Query parameters
            db  00h, 01h ; 00 01 - Number of questions
            db  00h, 00h ; 00 00 - Number of answers
            db  00h, 00h ; 00 00 - Number of authority records
            db  00h, 00h ; 00 00 - Number of additional records
            
            db  06h
            db  'g'
            db  'o'
            db  'o'
            db  'g'
            db  'l'
            db  'e'
            
            db  03h
            db  'c'
            db  'o'
            db  'm'
            
            db  00h ; 00 - zero byte to end the QNAME 
            
            db  00h, 01h ; 00 01 - QTYPE 
            db  00h, 01h ; 00 01 - QCLASS


 .code

_start:

_dns proc uses r12 r13 r14 r15 rbx

     local sockaddr         : sockaddr_in
     local cSocket          : qword
     local fullpacket[512]  : byte
    
         lea rdi, sockaddr
         mov rcx, sizeof sockaddr
         
         xor al, al
         rep stosb
         
         mov word ptr [sockaddr.sin_family], 02h ;AF_INET
         mov word ptr [sockaddr.sin_port], 3500h ;port 53 (dns)
         mov dword ptr [sockaddr.sin_addr], 01010101h ; 8.8.8.8 google dns
         
         mov rdi, 2 ;AF_INET
         mov rsi, 2 ;SOCK_DGRAM
         mov rdx, 0
         
         mov rax, socket
         syscall

         mov qword ptr [cSocket], rax
         
         mov rdi, qword ptr [cSocket]
         lea rsi, sockaddr
         mov rdx, 16
         
         mov rax, connect
         syscall

         mov rdi, qword ptr [cSocket]
         lea rsi, queryheader
         mov rdx, 28 ;len
         xor r10, r10 ;flags
         xor r8, r8 ;dest_addr
         xor r9, r9 ;addrlen
         
         mov rax, sendto
         syscall
         
         mov rdi, qword ptr [cSocket]
         lea rsi, fullpacket ;*buf
         mov rdx, 512 ;packetlen
         xor r10, r10 ;flags
         xor r8, r8 ;address
         xor r9, r9 ;addrlen
         
         mov rax, recv
         syscall
         
         mov rdi, 0
     
         mov rax, exit_group
         syscall
        
     ret

_dns endp

end


Works here. Note you do not exit properly so you will get a fault. What does strace say?

it exit on done. but it works long time when error. when all okay it done fast

i updated code without segmentation fault

it successfully works on root. but on user account of linux not works
